# A problem with height and width

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for a word of the English vocabulary (and speaking English since 50 years, I fear no good one exists).
So, my height is 1.90 m, my width is around 40 cm, give or take. I might climb the Mount Everest, then my height (in the other usage) is 8 km. Which probably would be rather unhealthy for me, but not as unhealthy as if I had a width of 8 km :-)
You see the problem? In my thesis, I thus can use "height" for an y coordinate, but using "latitude" or "x coordinate" sounds rather forced, and "width" seems plain wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here. What word are you looking for?

Comment: Well for one, both instances can be expressed as latitude and longitude, but it seems rather bizarre describing a person by those nouns. Instead of width, why not use 'girth' or 'breadth'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ground at an altitude of 0 feet, following statements are true:

- Your own height is 1.90 metres.
- You’re at a height of 0 metres. OR You’re at an altitude of 0 metres. **Note**: This height does not include your own height.
- Mount Everest’s height is 8000 metres.

When you’re up on Mount Everest, at its peak, following statements are true:

- Your own height is 1.90 metres.
- You’re at a height of 8000 metres. OR You’re at an altitude of 8000 metres. **Note**: This height does not include your own height.
- Mount Everest’s height is 8000 metres.

I hope this clears up the usage of words “height” in different contexts. Two things to note here:

- You don’t suddenly become 8000 metres **high** just because of your vertical location but does your **altitude** changes because of your vertical location? Yes.
- You don’t suddenly become 8000 metres **wide** just because you went 8000 metres away from your home but does your **distance from your home** changes because of your horizontal location? Yes.

Comment: Luckily, the problem does not pop up when I describe extrema: Then I can use highest vs. leftmost. But again, I can address the queen as Your Highness but not the spectator to my left as Your Leftness :-) In German everything is identical: "Breite" may be used for extension as well as location ("geographische Breite").

Answer (score 0):

If you climb Mount Everest, your height is still 1.90 m, and your *altitude* (or *height above sea level*) is 8 km. Your *distance* from Delhi will be 964 km.